# Sumifs to sum the column using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, range, sumifs

How to sum 4th column satisfying the difference between first and second column equal to 2 and also satisfying a criteria in the third column using excel formulas

Comment: Probably using SUMPRODUCT.

Answer (score 1):

use SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A2:A10-B2:B10=2)*(C2:C10="A")*D2:D10)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. But I have one more problem, I have missing values in column 1 and 2. When I applied the formula u mentioned it's returning # value due to missing values